# iOS app crashes when changing views

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt, unrecognized-selector

I am building an app that has many views. At one point, upon a press of a button, the view changes from one view back to the initial View Controller. The initial View Controller has nothing but the default code that gets added when creating a new class, the only thing it's used for is to hold buttons that are used to switch to other views. The view with the button has a textField, a "Quit" button and a couple labels. If I press the Quit button *without* touching the textField, all goes well, and I am taken back to the original view controller, where I am able to continue. However, if I decide to edit (or even just open the keyboard) on the textField, and then press the quit button, the app crashes, a sigabrt error. This is the error code I get.

```
2016-01-28 17:16:59.666 AutoTutor[64646:2461958] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ATPractice answerBox:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb58855d1e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104579e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103ff2deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010458248d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044cf90a ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044cf4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x0000000104928194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
6   UIKit                               0x0000000104a976fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
7   UIKit                               0x0000000104a979c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
8   UIKit                               0x00000001052ff506 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 298
9   UIKit                               0x0000000104b346ea -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 292
10  UIKit                               0x00000001052ff330 -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 49
11  UIKit                               0x0000000104b34799 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
12  UIKit                               0x00000001052ff1fd -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 136
13  UIKit                               0x00000001049c9605 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 161
14  UIKit                               0x00000001049c9b32 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 71
15  UIKit                               0x00000001049c9950 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 99
16  UIKit                               0x0000000104a93493 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke596 + 739
17  UIKit                               0x0000000104a8d756 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 111
18  UIKit                               0x0000000104c62e0b -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 42
19  UIKit                               0x0000000104a91159 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183
20  UIKit                               0x000000010532cd20 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 101
21  UIKit                               0x0000000104a8a90f -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252
22  UIKit                               0x0000000104a8a620 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1344
23  UIKit                               0x0000000104a8cd8c -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
24  UIKit                               0x00000001049b02af -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 241
25  UIKit                               0x00000001049b065e -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80
26  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107370fa0 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107f8e49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107f762af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044d9d09 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010449b2c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010449a828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
32  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107a2aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
33  UIKit                               0x0000000104926610 UIApplicationMain + 171
34  AutoTutor                           0x000000010379a8ef main + 111
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107fc292d start + 1
36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

ATPractice is the name of the class used for the View Controller with the textField, and answerBox is the name of the textField. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The initial viewController's .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Nothing going on in there, it's the default contents.

The initial viewController's .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@end
```

Again, default contents.

View Controller with the quit button's .m file

```
#import "ATPractice.h"
#import "DDMathParser.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ATPractice ()

@end

@implementation ATPractice

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender     {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Default contents with some extra imports.

View Controller with the quit button's .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ATPractice : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UILabel *instructionsLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *percentageLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabel;

IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
IBOutlet UITextField *answerBox;

IBOutlet UIScrollView *zoomView;

NSInteger questionInt;
NSInteger levelInt;
}
@end
```

Just some IBOutlets and NSIntegers.

Comment: It will be hard to help without any code, the relevant places I would search would be the action which "quit" button launches, and if you are setting the delegate of the `UITextField` the corresponding delegate methods

Comment: If `answerBox` is a property, my guess is somewhere you're calling `answerBox:` when you should be calling `answerBox` without the colon.

Comment: @MarkE The only action the quit button has is a modal segue to the initial View Controller. The .m files for both View Controllers are empty aside from the default code that comes with it when you create a new file. The .h file for the initial View Controller has just the default contents, while the .h for the one with the quit button has a few imports (````#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>````, ````#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>```` and UIKit). The rest are just IBOutlets and NSIntegers. How do I set the UITextField delegate?

Comment: @chedabob I don't have any instances of "answerBox:" at all in the app.

Comment: Check your nibs/storyboards that you've not got any stray connections. It looks like there might be one on your UITextField for one of its actions.

Comment: @chedabob I checked that like 7 times before, but I rechecked for good measure, I realized that I had connected EditingDidEnd for no reason without noticing. Thanks! If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your nibs/storyboards that you've not got any stray connections. It looks like there might be one on your UITextField for one of its actions.